# Get posts foreach categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 4

Here is my Controller:

```
public function getArticles()
{
    $categories = Category::with(['posts' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take(4)->get();
    }])->get();

    return View::make('articles', compact('categories'));
}
```

Here is my View:

```
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <h1>{{$category->title}}</h1>
        <ul>
            @foreach($category->posts as $post)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ $post->url() }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
```

My Category Model:

```
class Category extends Basemodel {
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

And my Post Model:

```
class Post extends Basemodel {
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

So it displays correctly my 6 categories (titles), but it only displays 4 posts total, I would like to display the 4 latest posts for each category (24 posts total).
I tried many things, and searched online but couldn't find a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using `limit` in the eager loading closure, because, as you noticed, it limits the other query, that fetches all the posts.

You can easily get single related model with eager loading for `hasMany` with a helper relation:

```
public function latestPost()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Post')->latest();
}
```

but for **n related models per each parent**, you need a bit more complex solution - take a look at:

1. [n per parent](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/)
2. [1 per parent](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/)

Comment: Thanks for those links. I followed the 2nd one strictly, but when I want to echo 
    `@foreach($categories as $category)
      <p>{{ $category->latestPost()->title }}</p>
     @endforeach` 
It gives me `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$title`

Comment: It's not `latestPost()` but `latestPost` - read about dynamic properties of `Eloquent` in the laravel docs.

Comment: I tried `{{ $category->latestPost->title }}` in the `foreach` loop and it returns `Trying to get property of non-object`. I triple checked everywhere, there's no mistakes, and I also updated composer and dump-autoload...

Comment: Actually, I have some empty categories (no posts in some of the categories), the error might come from here, I'm gonna check.

Comment: Update: Yes, problem was coming from there (empty categories) ~ I feel bad for not seeing that earlier! Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.

Comment: Just a quick question though, I want 4 latest posts for each category, so I replaced `hasOne('Post')->latest()` by `hasMany('Post')->take(4)`, and now it fetches 4 posts total, instead of 4 posts per category (in my foreach loop). So same problem I had in my original query. I guess there's no way around that or maybe the "n per parent" as you suggested, but that looks complicated...

Comment: No, as I said you can't do this just like that! Check the other article I linked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you can get use $categories = Category::all() to get all categories first.
2. foreach $categories and get the latest four posts by $posts=$category->posts
3. merge the posts array into one array
4. pass categories and posts to the view.

Cheers.

I hope you can write the correct foreach. And when retrieving the posts, use $category->posts instead of $category->posts(), which results in an error.

Comment: That's what I did in the beginning, but how to unmerge all the posts that are in this one big array, and display them by category...? That sounds quite messy